# Flutter ios MobileFFmpegConfig.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, mobile-ffmpeg

After build ios app in flutter project error occurred

```
'mobileffmpeg/MobileFFmpegConfig.h' file not found
```

even class exits in pods

[image]

Error:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to check this :

https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg/issues/118

Answer (score 0):

If you're on flutter SDK 2.12.X, the error is probably because of function rename. So go to your podfile...

It seems that the function flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods was changed to flutter_install_plugin_pods in the new version.

I fixed this issue by replace lines:

```
def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
↓
def flutter_install_plugin_pods(application_path = nil, relative_symlink_dir, platform)

plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
↓
plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file, platform)
```

Good luck.

Credit: [chainzhang](https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg/issues/303#issuecomment-851878858)